# How to take the header values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, api

Here i am calling one API, i am getting success response but they returning the total count header part , i don't know how to take the values.
See Here:
[image]

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '//www.examples.com/api/get/',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  },
  error: function(errMsg) { 
    //console.log(errMsg); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Try `Response` tab.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: request.getResponseHeader('x-Total-Count') in success callback

```
$.ajax({
  url: '//www.examples.com/api/get/',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('x-Total-Count'));
   },
  error: function(errMsg) { 
    //console.log(errMsg); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the success callback has 3 params, you can Click [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '//www.examples.com/api/get/',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function (result, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Count'));
  },
  error: function(errMsg) { 
    //console.log(errMsg); 
  }
});
```